# Using standard Roman numeral analysis how should 7th and 9th qualities be determined?

Tags: theory, harmony, roman-numerals

Example:

`C: V7` or inversions like `C: V6/5` are understood to be dominant-seventh chords and `C: V9` a dominant ninth chord with a diatonic, major ninth.

I think the basic idea is all the Arabic numeral parts are understood to be diatonic *relative to the root indicated by the Roman numeral*.

`V9` in `C` major the root of `V` is `G` and the 9th above that root is `A` which is a major ninth.

By comparison `iii9` in `C` major the root of `iii` is `E` and the 9th above that root is `F` which is a minor ninth.

That seems clear enough, but what about when the Roman numeral symbol indicates a *chromatic chord?*

Examples:

`C: V9/ii` or `Am: I7` or `C: iv9`

When secondary or borrowed symbols are used I understand that we are *temporarily referencing a new tonic/key* and I sort of expect the Arabic numerals should then be relative to the temporarily referenced tonic/key.

If that is way it should be done, I get these examples...

`C: V9/ii` is a secondary dominant relative to tonic/key `Dm` and `V9` in `Dm` would get a minor-ninth. So the chord `C: V9/ii` is `A C# E G Bb`.

`Am: I7` is a borrowed chord relative to parallel major `A` major and `I7` in `A` would get a major-seventh. So the chord `Am: I7` is `A C# E G#`.

`C: iv9` is a borrowed chord relative to parallel minor `Cm` and `iv9` in `Cm` would get a major-ninth. So the chord `C: iv9` is `F Ab C Eb G`.

I think the confusion is when using secondary or borrowed chord the RNA symbol isn't relative to the key denoted by the colon `C:` , `Am:`, etc. but by the *secondary slash or switching of upper/lower case which indicates a temporary tonic/key or mode change from the key denoted by the colon.*

...is this correct?

Comment: The first half of this is a great question, but I didn't really get your examples; what do you mean by relative?

Comment: 'iii9 is Em9' spelled E G B D F? Yes, diatonically, but surely a m9 rooted on E is E G B D F#? And 'C iv9 is *relative*. Isn't it *parallel*?(Same as Am: A maj.) I appreciate this question was not easy to put together!

Comment: @Tim I think `iii9` is `Emb9` rather than `Em9`. It's hard to not be wordy, but my question/suggestion is RNA is diatonic and jazz symbols aren't - to me the jazz symbols are all relative to a dominant chord and its extensions in a major key.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic, relative to a tonic/key. Ex. `V` surely that is _relative to something_ or else you wouldn't be able to know the specific notes to play. Let me try adding some edits in my final three examples.

Comment: @Michael: could you post an example of literature? I‘m not sure whether I understand your question. Do you mean that if we are in am and A7 occurs as V7/D it would be unclear whether in RNA was I7 or V7? And if one analysis I7 would this mean a minor or a major 9th?

Comment: Michael Curtis, the iii9 in C major is actually Em***7*** (♭9).

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli, with that particular case I was not thinking secondary dominant, but perhaps a Picardy third ending, something like jazz symbols `Amin... E7 to Amaj7`, in RNA should it be `i... V7 I7`. The question being on the final chord is the 7 M7 or m7 and how to write that figure. Normally RNA doesn't add modifiers to `7` like jazz symbols.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya. I know that the diatonic `iii` ninth chord is. Question is not how to write the jazz symbol, but the RNA symbol. Are all RNA figures assumed to be diatonic? I think yes. How then to write RNA in a chromatics context. with plain daitonic `iii` it should be simple `iii9` in RNA is `E G B D F` in jazz you specify `b9`, in RNA it's already assume to be a diatonic 9th, therefore a minor `m9`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple variants of RNA in common use. The distinguishing styles V, v, V<sup>+</sup>, v° will be readily recognized as symbols for major, minor, augmented, and diminished *triads* over a root that is a diatonic scale degree (for a chromatic root, a prefixed accidental must be used, as ♭II<sup>6</sup> for the Neapolitan sixth).

However, there seems to be no similarly standard convention for distinguishing qualities of 7th and 9th chords, apart from vii°<sup>7</sup> and vii<sup>ø7</sup> for diminished and half-diminished 7th chords respectively. The most sensible convention is to style the Roman numeral according to the quality of the underlying triad and assume the added notes are diatonic unless indicated otherwise, for instance

- C: iii<sup>9</sup> is E-G-B-D-F (= Em<sup>7♭9</sup> in jazz notation)
- C: V<sup>9</sup>/ii is diatonic *in the key of ii,* i.e. A-C♯-E-G-B♭
- C: I<sup>7</sup> (or I<sup>M7</sup>, etc.) is a major seventh chord; C: I<sup>♭7</sup> or I<sup>dom7</sup> is a dominant seventh chord (a.k.a. V<sup>7</sup>/IV, but with different functional implications)
- C: iv<sup>9</sup> is F-A♭-C-E-G, a perfectly normal mixed-mode chord.

In minor keys the picture is muddied by the presence of multiple variants of the 6th and 7th scale degrees. Unfortunately for the standardization-minded, a: VII (G-B-D) and a: vii° (G♯-B-D) are in common use. Musically, 7ths and 9ths of chords tend to be drawn from the *natural* minor scale because they typically resolve downward. Therefore, I'd interpret a: i<sup>7</sup> as a *minor* seventh (common in sequences) unless clearly written otherwise, e.g. a: i<sub>♯7</sub><sup>9</sup> (sorry I can't make the numerals vertically aligned).

Comment: `Idom7` seems like a jazz oriented RNA mod, `V7/IV` is the usual, functional RNA symbol.

Comment: `Cm:iv9` would be `F Ab C Eb G` so shouldn't the borrowed chord `C:iv9` be the same set of notes? `F Ab C Eb G`

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I saw Idom7 in Aldwell & Schachter for the first chord of Beethoven's 1st Symphony. The point they were making is that the chord, in addition to being V7/IV, can be retrospectively heard as a modified tonic.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis And as to C:iv9, changing the case of the Roman numerals is not the same as moving to the parallel mode (e.g. C:III would be E major, different from Cm:III) so I feel justified in saying that only the third of the chord is affected.

Comment: That's an interesting point about `C:IV` versus `C:iv`, the later I understand to mean borrowed chord rather than "lower the third."

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is developed from recent questions concerning accidentals whether they are chromatic or diatonic.

It is a question concerning analysis and different analysis systems : RNA and analysis of Jazz/Pop.

In Jazz - and the Riemann/Maler system would be no confusion while in the RNA you have to decide for modulation or not. If your analysis is continuing in the new key the (V7) are minor 7th and (V9) are minor when they are secondary dominants to ii,iii and vi degree.

If your not changing the key in your analysis there will be no confusion by adding a small flat in front of the 7 in case of I becomes a secondary dominant to IV (as in Jazz the V7b5).

Comment: Yes, the question is about RNA and specifically about _temporary_ chromaitic harmony, not modulations, so how to understand 7 and 9 figures when the RNA is a secondary chord or a borrowed chord. I gave examples to illustrate both cases.

Comment: I understand your last sentence about adding accidentals  - sort of cautionary accidentals to numeric figures as a kind of imitation of jazz or figured bass, but the question is specifically if RNA always assumes _diatonic_ intervals which are diatonic to the relative/temporary tonic.