# Can any chord be converted to its roman numeral equivalent?

Tags: chords, roman-numerals

Just a quick question, but I'm wondering if *any* type of chord even something complicated Gbmaj13#5/F can be converted to roman numerals? Assuming the key is given.

Comment: I think this question - while not a dup - overlaps with mine https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82074 which hasn't been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! Since the Roman-numeral system really only tells you the root—some systems don't even clarify quality of the chord—you simply give the Roman numeral of the root and show the extensions with the figured bass right next to it.

In D♭ major, your G♭maj13♯5/F would just be IVmaj13♯5 in first inversion.

Note that I say "in first inversion" here; the figured bass for extended tertians (chords larger than 7ths) gets pretty ugly. It's best to just say "in first inversion" or add "/F" instead of trying to use the figured bass for these chords.

Now, with all that said, Roman-numeral notation isn't typically used in styles where chords like this exist. If your music uses a lot of chords like this, we'd tend to just label it G♭maj13♯5/F. (At least, I would.)